# Merge two queries into one in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need to make the following two queries into one but can't, When I try to test it it doesnt run at all and I'm not sure why. If anyone could help I would be thankful.
This is my first query -

```
$exportArray[] = $row['reviewId'];
$row_num++;

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM review WHERE (reviewForum = "$reviewForum")
```

And this is my second -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mom WHERE ( reviewId = " . $row['reviewId'] . " )";
```

I tried UNION but doesn't work either. The common fields between the two tables is reviewId. I am querying two tables and the first query above works but when I try to include the second one I can't get it to work. Thanks if anyone can help me, it's probably something small but I've been looking at it for a while now and it's very annoying at this stage.

Comment: what is common between two tables?

Comment: is it possible to show us the two tables' structure?

Comment: @FahimParkar reviewId is common between the two tables. See the fields I need from the mom table are reviewDate, result, qualityRankingOfReview and inputDocRank. So I am wondering do I need to do a JOIN or something? It needs to take 
   ( reviewId = " . $row['reviewId'] . " )" aswell as 
    (reviewForum = "$reviewForum")

Comment: @davef : Please updated this in question

Comment: @davef : check shakir answer. I believe that is what you are looking for...

Comment: @FahimParkar Done it there, is that what you mean?

Comment: the details that you provided "reviewId is common between the two tables. ...." should be there in question because all read questions.. no one read these comments much...

Comment: Thanks, I changed it there. Also tried Shakir's answer but no success.

Comment: It's not an error, its just not taking information from two rows and I don't no why. 

The way the guy below has it done works fine BUT it doesn't take information from two rows and I don't no why, it should but its just not.The fields I want it to get out of the mom table are result, date, qualityRankingOfReview and inputDocRank. Its getting result and date but not the last two, I honestly can't see why its not seeing as it is getting the first two

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM review a
JOIN mom b 
ON a.reviewId=b.reviewId
WHERE a.reviewForum ='$reviewForum'
```

I assume, reviewId is in both tables

Comment: Tried it there, it gets everything bar information from two rows :( I just need it to get qualityRankingOfReview and inputDocRank from the mom table to make it work.

EDIT - Its weird, its getting the information from the mom table but leaving out the two rows I need...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.*,r.* 
FROM review r
  LEFT JOIN mom m 
    ON r.reviewId = m.reviewId
WHERE r.reviewForum = "$reviewForum"
```